# Calling a function when opening a react-native screen

Tags: function, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to load a JSON from AsyncStorage every time a user opens one of my react-native screens (I'm using StackNavigator). This JSON contains information on what my states should be set to.

**How can I call a function that runs every time this screen is opened?**

Further info:
I've written a function that updates my states according to a JSON loaded from AsyncStorage. The function works perfectly when called from a button, but when the function is called from `render()`, part of my screen freezes and some buttons are not touchable anymore. Strangely only TextInput still works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `componentWillMount()` method. This will execute automatically before `render()` method gets triggered.

```
class Sample extends Component{
    state = {data : []};
    componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({data : inputObject});
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
            //you can render the data here
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

```
const Sample = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        setState(inputObject);
    }, [])

    return(
         <View>
         //you can render the data here
         </View>
    );

}
```

Reference: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

Comment: That method is marked as legacy and should not be used anymore: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Comment: @divine  componentWillMount() call every time when I m back to screen? like in ios viewWillApppear

Comment: @Jaydip componentWillMount() will be called before the render method is invoked. you could prevent the render method from getting invoked in componentWillMount() thereby preventing the screen from displaying the intended output. componentDidMount() will get invoked after the render method is invoked.

Comment: Hmm, gives me, "Cannot find name componentWillMount"

Comment: `componentWillMount` is deprecated and also removed(if iam not wrong). Please check [this post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html) to see alternatives for `componentWillMount`. i have transitioned to working with angular, so i wouldn't be able to validate my recommendation.

Comment: @divine can you implement this with a functional component

Comment: @CurtisCrentsil functional components are supposed to be stateless. but i think react has added features into functional component that will enable them to be stateful. this answer was written in 2017, now its june2020. i'm not working on reactNative anymore. sorry, i wouldn't be able to provide accurate details on this

Answer (score 3):

If you want to handle back button page navigation then you need to listen to the
navigation event once when the component has mounted, use the code below for the same.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.focusListener = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus',
       () => { 
               console.log('focus is called'); 
              //your logic here.
       }
     );
}
```

Comment: It's important to note that this is a feature in react-navigation version 4+

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily accomplished using 'withNavigationFocus' , found in the react native documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/function-after-focusing-screen.html)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { withNavigationFocus } from 'react-navigation';

class TabScreen extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.isFocused !== this.props.isFocused) {
      // Use the `this.props.isFocused` boolean
      // Call any action
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <View />;
  }
}

// withNavigationFocus returns a component that wraps TabScreen and passes
// in the navigation prop
export default withNavigationFocus(TabScreen);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `hook` approach:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I literally just copied the first example of the documentation, but it's a very good one.
If you want continue reading: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

I used "onLayout" method inside the view.

[read the doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#onlayout)

> onLayout: Invoked on mount and on layout changes.

```
export default function Login({ navigation }) {

  const executeOnLoad = () => {
    console.log("view has loaded!");
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container} onLayout={executeOnLoad}>
    --- layout code here
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with the screen, I will suggest you use useFocusEffect hooks.

example:

```
const ExampleScreen = () => {
    // your code here
    useFocusEffect(useCallback(() => {
       // your logic goes here
    }, []))
    return (
        <View>
           {/* render your content here */}
        </View>
    )
}
```